# The related object is not in the DB yet when I would like to use it

Tags: django, django-models

I am currently writing a wrapped django app for the Google Calendar API. (My plan is to make it open source, if I ever finish it properly.)

The django site's users can be added as guests to the events, and this action is to be syncronized to google calendar. Here are the relevant code pieces:

```
class Event(models.Model):

    def _convert_to_gcal_data(self):
        # removed some code here ...

        # and the interesting bit is
        for attendee in self.attendee_set.all():
            data['attendees'].append({
                'displayName': attendee.user.name,
                'email': attendee.user.email,
                'responseStatus': attendee.response_status,
            })
        return data

    def update_to_gcal(self):
        """
        Updates the remote event db from local data
        :return:
        """
        service = cal_utils.get_service(settings.GOOGLE_CAL_USER, settings.GOOGLE_CAL_CERT)
        data = self._convert_to_gcal_data()
        return service.events().update(calendarId=self.calendar.cal_id, eventId=self.ev_id, sendNotifications=False, body=data).execute()

    def register_user(self, user):
        self.attendee_set.create(user=user, response_status='accepted')
        self.update_to_gcal()
```

Despite the create method creating the user in `attendee_set`, the call to `attendee_set.all()` in `_convert_to_gcal_data` returns an empty queryset. I guess the create did not commit yet.

How can I work around this behaviour of django?

**Update**

Checking my tests more carefully, I've found that the described behaviour is present only if I call the `register_user` method from the view, not when I call it directly as I do in my tests.

Comment: There is no kind of "delayed commit" in standard Django. Are you running this on App Engine or some database with eventual consistency?

Comment: Nope. I'm currently running it locally in sqlite. My hosted instance uses postgres db, I'll check if the problem exists there too, and will report back.

Comment: The problem exists with postgres too.

Comment: Has the `self` Event been saved when you call `register_user`?

Comment: Yes. The Event exists "a long time ago".

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the view. I was doing a prefetch related on `assignee_set`, and this caused it not to be reevaluated after the assignee set has changed.

Removing prefetch related from the view code solved the issue.